# Redirect user only after login

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a search input to search for the required subject. I am able to display the appropriate result, I want the result to be displayed but user can only to go to the link if he logins, else display message box "You have to login to be able to go to another page". The problem here is i can't seem to display the error message at all. I want to display the result even if user is not or is logged in. Just that directing him to another page display error message and he must login or he cant be directed

```
<form class="search">
                <div class="form-group input">
                <div class="icon-addon">
                <input type="text" name="type" class="st-search" id="search" placeholder="Search"  autocomplete="off" >
                <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
                </div>
                <h4 id="results-text">Showing: <b id="search-string">Output</b></h4>
                <ul id="results"></ul>                                  
        </div>      
</form>
```

find.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "hostname";
$dbname = "databasename";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

global $task_db;

$task_db = new mysqli();
$task_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$task_db->set_charset("utf8");

if ($task_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("You can't connect: %s\n", $task_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    // If user is not logged in
    if(!$_SESSION['login']){
        $message = 'You are not logged in';
        echo $message;
   die;
    }
//if user is logged in, user can be redirected to the link. Something is not right here
else{
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="url">';
$html .= '<h3>name</h3>';

$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search = $task_db->real_escape_string($search);

if (strlen($search) >= 1 && $search !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
    $result = $task_db->query($query) or trigger_error($task_db->error."[$query]");
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {
            $name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search."</b>", $result['subject_Name']);
            //display url
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/'.urlencode($result['subject_Name']).'&lang=en';
            $output = str_replace('name', $name, $html);
            $output = str_replace('url', $url, $output);
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{
        // No Results found
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Remove `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` from find.php, this variable should be set from your login page.

Answer (score 0):

First session_start(); shoul be the first command
Second

```
 $_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

sets $_SESSION['login'] allway to true so that

```
if(!$_SESSION['login']){
```

will never happen.

Comment: `session_start()` doesn't need to be first function to be called, it just needs to be called before any `output` to the screen...

Comment: but if user is not logged in, I can still display the search result. Just that i need the user to login to be linked to another page.

Comment: i know , it's more a "should be" as a 2must be" to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you set `$_SESSION['login'] = true;`
so the check `if (!$_SESSION['login']){` will never be true.

You always get the result;

```
//$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

When your user login set the `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` but not just before the `if (!$_SESSION['login']){` line

Comment: But in what way should I place the if else statement because i want to display the result even if user is not or is logged in. Just that directing him to another page display error message and he must login or he cant be directed